# Forgot to create a feature branch and created a commit on master which should have been on feature

Tags: git, branch

I forgot to create a feature branch from `master` branch, and then changed some file and created a commit. How shall I do now?

Answer (score 3):

Create the feature branch where master is (`git branch featureA master`) then reposition master on master~1: `git checkout master; git reset --hard HEAD~1`.

Comment: Thanks. Does `git branch featureA master`, regardless of which is the current branch, work the same as `git checkout -b featureA` when the current branch is `master`?

Comment: sure... although if you are in master, you actually don't need to checkout featureA because you will then have to checkout master to be able to move it. If you are on master, you could do it like this: ```git branch featureA; git reset --hard HEAD~1```

Comment: Thanks. What if I should have created a feature branch from another existing branch `develop`, but i accidentally created a commit on `master`?

Comment: So... let's see if I got it right. You should have created a branch featureA on top of develop, but instead did it on 'master', you have already committed and now you want to set it "right"? Well.... assuming that develop and master are not on the same revision (which is what will normally happen) then a cherry-pick is what you should do. Let's assume it's 10 commits on featureA: ```git checkout --detach develop; git cherry-pick featureA~10..featureA; git branch -f featureA```. That should do. (it's also possible to go it with rebase but I have to _assimilate it_ before I use it in recipes).

Comment: Yes, you understand my question. Thanks, Edmundo!

Answer (score 2):

This solution assumes you currently have the `master` branch checked out. If you don't, you should switch to it:

```
$ git checkout master
```

First, create a branch for your feature so you don't lose your work:

```
$ git branch newfeature
```

Second, remove this commit from the master, as it doesn't belong there (like you noted in the question):

```
$ git reset HEAD~ --hard
```

Finally, check out your feature branch, and continue working on your feature:

```
$ git checkout newfeature
```

Comment: Thanks. Which command  creates a new feature branch, `git branch newfeature` or   `git branch -b newfeature`?

Comment: `git branch newfeature` creates a new branch. The `git branch` command doesn't have a `-b` flag - you are probably muddling it up with `git checkout -b newfeature` which is a shortcut that both creates a new branch and checks it out in one go.